# changing embeded twitter by alternating url with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

```
<article class="result">
<h2 id="twUrl"><blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><a id="twlk" href=""></a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></h2>
</article>
```

```
<scirpt>
function twChange(){
var twtw = result["a"]
$("#twlk").attr("href",twtw);
}
twChange();


var result = {{"a":"TWitterUrl1"},
              {"b":"TWitterUrl2"},
              {"c":"TWitterUrl3"}}
</script>
```

I'm trying to embed tweets in my Web by passing in a tweets URL.

I want to change blockquote herf directly.
But it doesn't work....

Comment: note the typo in your `script` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your object like this:

```
var result = {
  "a": "TWitterUrl1",
  "b": "TWitterUrl2",
  "c": "TWitterUrl3"
}
```

```js
var result = {
  "a": "TWitterUrl1",
  "b": "TWitterUrl2",
  "c": "TWitterUrl3"
}

function twChange() {
  var twtw = result["a"]
  $("#twlk").attr("href", twtw);
}
twChange();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="result">
  <h2 id="twUrl">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
      <a id="twlk" href="">link</a>
    </blockquote>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </h2>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your json object in an array bracket [].

```
<scirpt>
function twChange(){
var twtw = result["a"]
$("#twlk").attr("href",twtw);
}
twChange();


var result = [{"a":"TWitterUrl1"},
              {"b":"TWitterUrl2"},
              {"c":"TWitterUrl3"}]
</script>
```